# C#.NET and parsing XML response from server

Tags: c#, .net, xml, quickbooks, qbxml

I have several years experience working with JS, Python, and JSON, but just started working with C#.NET and XML within the past week.

I'm having to write a solution for Quickbooks Desktop to consolidate multiple invoice line items into one line item. The examples I have from Intuit are like +10 years old. It isn't entirely clear to me from SO topics what a modern approach is for my use case: either the answers are +6 years old or it has to do with reading from files--I'm trying to parse a response.

Here is what the server response looks like (I am temporarily writing it to a file) followed by some questions:

```
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRs>
    <InvoiceQueryRs requestID="0" statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status OK">

      <!-- RECORD 1 -->
      <InvoiceRet>
        <TxnID>3B58B-1540309911</TxnID>
        <EditSequence>1540587328</EditSequence>
        <TxnNumber>27058</TxnNumber>
        <CustomerRef>
          <ListID>800006FF-1540307596</ListID>
          <FullName>Test Co.:Test 1</FullName>
        </CustomerRef>
        <RefNumber>L-9</RefNumber>
        <Subtotal>2212.00</Subtotal>
        <BalanceRemaining>2212.00</BalanceRemaining>
        <IsPaid>false</IsPaid>

        <!-- RECORD 1: INVOICE LINE ITEM 1 -->
        <InvoiceLineRet>
          <TxnLineID>3B58D-1540309911</TxnLineID>
          <ItemRef>
            <ListID>80000002-1443563699</ListID>
            <FullName>Consulting Fees</FullName>
          </ItemRef>
          <Desc>PROJECT: Test 1; TASK: Wrap-up</Desc>
          <Quantity>6</Quantity>
          <Rate>220</Rate>
          <Amount>1320.00</Amount>
        </InvoiceLineRet>

        <!-- RECORD 1: INVOICE LINE ITEM 2 -->
        <InvoiceLineRet>
          <TxnLineID>3B58E-1540309911</TxnLineID>
          <ItemRef>
            <ListID>80000002-1443563699</ListID>
            <FullName>Consulting Fees</FullName>
          </ItemRef>
          <Desc>PROJECT: Test 1; TASK: Kickoff</Desc>
          <Quantity>4</Quantity>
          <Rate>220</Rate>
          <Amount>880.00</Amount>
        </InvoiceLineRet>

        <!-- RECORD 1: INVOICE LINE ITEM 3 -->
        <InvoiceLineRet>
          <TxnLineID>3B58F-1540309911</TxnLineID>
          <ItemRef>
            <ListID>80000025-1538518495</ListID>
            <FullName>Travel:Travel Meals</FullName>
          </ItemRef>
          <Desc>DATE: Oct 23, 2018; PROJECT: Test 1</Desc>
          <Rate>12</Rate>
          <Amount>12.00</Amount>
        </InvoiceLineRet>
      </InvoiceRet>

      <!-- RECORD 2 -->
      <InvoiceRet>
        <TxnID>3B595-1540830324</TxnID>
        <EditSequence>1540830324</EditSequence>
        <TxnNumber>27060</TxnNumber>
        <CustomerRef>
          <ListID>80000700-1540307618</ListID>
          <FullName>Test Co.:Test 2</FullName>
        </CustomerRef>
        <RefNumber>L-11</RefNumber>
        <Subtotal>2760.00</Subtotal>
        <BalanceRemaining>2760.00</BalanceRemaining>

        <!-- RECORD 2: INVOICE LINE ITEM 1 -->
        <InvoiceLineRet>
          <TxnLineID>3B597-1540830324</TxnLineID>
          <ItemRef>
            <ListID>80000002-1443563699</ListID>
            <FullName>Consulting Fees</FullName>
          </ItemRef>
          <Desc>PROJECT: Test 2; TASK: Prebill Task</Desc>
          <Rate>1000</Rate>
          <Amount>1000.00</Amount>
        </InvoiceLineRet>

        <!-- RECORD 2: INVOICE LINE ITEM 2 -->
        <InvoiceLineRet>
          <TxnLineID>3B598-1540830324</TxnLineID>
          <ItemRef>
            <ListID>80000002-1443563699</ListID>
            <FullName>Consulting Fees</FullName>
          </ItemRef>
          <Desc>PROJECT: Test 2; TASK: Present Findings</Desc>
          <Quantity>3</Quantity>
          <Rate>0.00</Rate>
          <Amount>0.00</Amount>
        </InvoiceLineRet>

        <!-- RECORD 2: INVOICE LINE ITEM 3 -->
        <InvoiceLineRet>
          <TxnLineID>3B599-1540830324</TxnLineID>
          <ItemRef>
            <ListID>80000002-1443563699</ListID>
            <FullName>Consulting Fees</FullName>
          </ItemRef>
          <Desc>PROJECT: Test 2; TASK: Research</Desc>
          <Quantity>2</Quantity>
          <Rate>220</Rate>
          <Amount>440.00</Amount>
        </InvoiceLineRet>

        <!-- RECORD 2: INVOICE LINE ITEM 4 -->
        <InvoiceLineRet>
          <TxnLineID>3B59A-1540830324</TxnLineID>
          <ItemRef>
            <ListID>80000002-1443563699</ListID>
            <FullName>Consulting Fees</FullName>
          </ItemRef>
          <Desc>PROJECT: Test 2; TASK: Project Launch</Desc>
          <Quantity>6</Quantity>
          <Rate>220</Rate>
          <Amount>1320.00</Amount>
        </InvoiceLineRet>
      </InvoiceRet>

    </InvoiceQueryRs>
  </QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```

1. In general, what is the modern approach to parsing this so that each element can be referred to?

Something like `xml.InvoiceRet[0].TxnId` which would be `3B58B-1540309911`.

2. How is each record referred to given that the parent node `<InvoiceRet>` is nondescript? Do you have to iterate through each `<InvoiceRet>`?

What I have tried from the Intuit documentation:

```
// this is where the query is sent to the QB and response is returned
var responseSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestSet);

// take the response and get the first element, I guess?
var response = responseSet.ResponseList.GetAt(0);
var customerRetList = response.Detail as ICustomerRetList;

// print the number of records
// it should be 2, but comes back with nothing
Console.WriteLine(customerRetList.Count);
```

Comment: Does your service uses WSDL? If so, all you need to do is create a service proxy client. Either use VisualStudio to add a Service Reference, or use **svcutil** command to do so. It will generate your proxy classes.

Comment: It sounds like if I was using the Web Connector, WSDL be an option. This is just a desktop solution that runs on the same machine the user has QuickBooks desktop open in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like for my use case, [Basic Query (LINQ to XML)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-queries-linq-to-xml) would be the best option. Decided to parse the response to a string using:

```
// Do the request and get the response message set object
var responseSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestSet);

// Convert response to string
var responseXml = responseSet.ToXMLString();

// Then the LINQ to XML for the string that I'm still working through
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(responseXml);

// Set the xmlDoc root
var xmlDocRoot = xmlDoc.Root.Element("QBXMLMsgsRs")
                            .Element("InvoiceQueryRs")
                            .Elements("InvoiceRet");


// Iterate through the elements to get values and do some logic
foreach (var invoiceElement in xmlDocRoot)
{
    var editSequence = (string) invoiceElement.Element("EditSequence");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I put results into a datatable so results are flat.  I got results from a file.  The Load method with work with either a URL or filename.  Replace Load() with Parse() if you have a string.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("TxnID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("EditSequence", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("TxnNumber", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("CustomerRef_ListID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("CustomerRef_FullName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("RefNumber", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Subtotal", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("BalanceRemaining", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("IsPaid", typeof(Boolean));
            dt.Columns.Add("ItemRef_ListID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ItemRef_FullName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Desc", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Rate", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(decimal));


            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            foreach (XElement invoiceRet in doc.Descendants("InvoiceRet"))
            {
                string txnId = (string)invoiceRet.Element("TxnID");
                string editSequence = (string)invoiceRet.Element("EditSequence");
                string txnNumber = (string)invoiceRet.Element("TxnNumber");
                XElement customerRef = invoiceRet.Element("CustomerRef");
                string custListId = (string)customerRef.Element("ListID");
                string custFullName = (string)customerRef.Element("FullName");
                string refNumber = (string)invoiceRet.Element("RefNumber");
                decimal subtotal = (decimal)invoiceRet.Element("Subtotal");
                decimal balance = (decimal)invoiceRet.Element("BalanceRemaining");
                Boolean? isPaid = (Boolean?)invoiceRet.Element("IsPaid");

                foreach (XElement invoiceLine in invoiceRet.Elements("InvoiceLineRet"))
                {
                    string lineListId = (string)invoiceLine.Descendants("ListID").FirstOrDefault();
                    string lineFullName = (string)invoiceLine.Descendants("FullName").FirstOrDefault();
                    string desc = (string)invoiceLine.Element("Desc");
                    int? quantity = (int?)invoiceLine.Element("Quantity");
                    decimal rate = (decimal)invoiceLine.Element("Rate");
                    decimal amount = (decimal)invoiceLine.Element("Amount");

                    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                        txnId, editSequence, txnNumber, custListId, custFullName,
                        refNumber, subtotal, balance, isPaid, 
                        lineListId, lineFullName, desc, quantity, rate, amount 
                    });


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps will result into a C# object out of the XML, (provided that you have the source XSD files)

**Step 1 -- Grab the related XSD files**

Create Classes out of the XSD files provided by the provider of the XML SDK. In your case its QuickBooks SDK. Grab the related XSD files based on the targeted version of the QuickBooks software from the path:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Intuit\IDN\Common\tools\validator

**Step 2 -- Create Classes out of XSD defination files.**

Run this xsd command againts your parent xsd file such as

```
xsd QBCqbxmlops160.cs.xsd /classes
```

**Step 3 -- Include the classes in to your project**

Include the resultant C# class file into your project. This file contains a perfect tranlsation of C# classes, ENUMs, DataType conversions of all the XML specification with in QBXML parent node.

**Step 4 -- Convert XML to C# object**

```
//https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=net-7.0

string xmlResponseSgtring = "<QBXML><QBXMLMsgsRs>...";
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlResponseSgtring));
QBXML qbXmlResponseObject;
qbXmlResponseObject = (QBXML)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
```